# Please undelete Automatic Wallpaper Manager?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, deleted-questions

I ask NOT for a reopen here, but would you please undelete [this question](https://superuser.com/q/679640/269574,  so that at least, it can be shared, viewed, and benefit those who can't seek or see deleted posts? Undeletion will help me to ask it anew **elsewhere**.

Notwithstanding the close reason, the answers volunteered are supernal, inestimable and effective, and would truly help many others.

Answer (score 8):

> Undeletion will help me to ask it anew.

Asking again will just get it re-closed. The question is no more on-topic now than it was when asked.

The post was removed because it isn't the type of question we want to encourage on the site. Therefore, undeleting it would be counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my OP. Does it clarify?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal you have access to the question yourself, right? You should be able to view your own deleted questions. Other users don't need to be able to see it for you to have access to ask it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, no. I can view but not access? All options are greyed.

Comment: What else do you mean by "access" then? You can view the question, which is sufficient for you to copy the information for your use elsewhere.