# How to ask answerers to answer anew at another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, users

Pursuant to [Please undelete Automatic Wallpaper Manager?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8721/269574), I questioned anew at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13458/7064, but how can I inform the original answerers here about this so that they can post their superlatively hepful answers there? Would someone please help with this?

It is most righteous and principled for generous answerers Rik and Vignesh Palani to post themselves, because all acclaim and complimentary reputation should be attributed solely to them.

Comment: You can post  the answers yourself too.

Answer (score 10):

It's not about the reputation, or at least not all about the reputation. Answering questions and building up the knowledge base is the purpose. So if you already know the answer, and you are struggling to contact original poster, I would recommend you to answer your own question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

You can quote the %username% of Super User users who originally answered the question and maybe even link their profiles. No one will cry about few reputation points and possibly a lot of people will benefit from a good answer, no matter who posted it.

Comment: If you really don't want to earn "unfair" rep then post your answer as a community wiki.